# Failed to write to file: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, npm, javascript

I am trying to build a folder with the name of build which will gonna contains number of map files and JavaScript files. But i'm getting an issue shown below.

Code :

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "d2-manifest package.json manifest.webapp",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo Everything probably works great\\! ## karma start test/config/karma.config.js --single-run true",
    "build": "rm -rf build && set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress && npm run manifest",
    "postbuild": "cp -r src/i18n icon.png ./build/",
    "validate": "npm ls --depth 0",
    "manifest": "d2-manifest package.json build/manifest.webapp",
    "deploy": "npm run build && mvn clean deploy",
    "lint": "echo Looks good."
  }
```

Error :

[image: Error in cygwin "Failed to write to file: ENOENT: no such file or directory"]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply [code formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#code).

Answer (score 0):

(I'm ignoring the fact that you seem to run this on a Windows machine)

The `set` command does not do what you think it does. To set an environment variable for a command, use

```
VARIABLE=value cmd
```

or

```
env VARIABLE=value cmd
```

This means changing

```
set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress
```

into

```
env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress
```

With `set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress` you just set the positional parameters of the current shell instance to `NODE_ENV=production`, `webpack` and `--progress`.

Comment: sir if i didn't use set than I'll get the following error


`> rm -rf build && mkdir build && NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress && npm run manifest

'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
`

Comment: @gouravsachdeva Ok, but `set` is the wrong command. `env` is the correct command. I will update the answer.